# find Intel Processor Number for my cpu in linux

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit

How to find out the [Intel Processor Number](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html) for my CPU model on linux ?

I bought a server from a webhosting company and I don't know which CPU model it has. I only know it is a Pentium D , dual core. But the model can be one of the following: 805/820/830/840/915/925/935/945/920/930/940/950/960/955/965

But the /proc/cpuinfo shows model as '6' , so how do I find out the real cpu model? Because there is no Pentium D model 6 on the market.

```
z3 ~ # cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x4
cpu MHz     : 2997.084
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat     pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts  nopl pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5994.16
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: here is the correct answer to my question: http://superuser.com/questions/324584/how-to-determine-the-spec-code-of-an-intel-processor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model or cpu_model is An integer that is vendor dependent and indicates their version of the cpu_family. Model 6 refers to the 9xx series. So if we look at your clock speed it should be either a 925 or a 930.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be 100% sure what your cpu (unless you have physical acces) but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeron) your cpu is the following one:

```
PIn Intel's "Family/Model/Stepping" scheme, Cedar Mill Celeron Ds and Pentium 4s
are family 15, model 6, and their Intel product code is 80552.
```

Comment: it is not my cpu , because the model number of mine is '6'

Comment: sorry, looked wrong, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

In most circumstances the method you're using should show the model name, mine says:

`Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8400  @ 2.26GHz` for my laptop.

Even my EC2 instance reports a model:
`model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz`

Other ways to check:

`cat /var/log/dmesg | grep -i 'processor'`

I get a line like this:

`[    0.067571] CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8400  @ 2.26GHz stepping 0a`

You could also check the output from `dmidecode -t 4` or `lshw -class cpu'`

Comment: nope, dmidecode, lshw or dmesg don't show the model number that is used to market the product. It would be showing in /proc/cpuinfo, but my output doesn't have model number in it